# Is there a way to limit number of characters in input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, input

I have an input of type file, my question is: after I select the file, can the file name be limited to a certain number of characters ?

Comment: This isn't enough to work with. Limited how, where, for what?

Comment: File-name, no. Well, sorta, but not sure why you would want to do this. You can get the filename from the input's value.

Comment: In its current form, this question is useless. -1.

Comment: This is the case: if someone selects for upload a file with a very long title, after selecting the file, the text that is displayed in the input, before the actual upload, should be limited to the first 10-15 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the file name using

```
var filename = document.getElementById('file-id').value;
filename = filename.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
```

But limitation in sense, after uploading the file you can get the file name using above approach.

Then you can have

```
if (filename.length < 100 ) {
  //do something
}
```

**FYI:** Evert thing happens only after the file being uploaded in client side.  There is no use in limiting the filepath before uploaded to server.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
var limit = 8;

var fileName = document.getElementById("file-name-field").value();

// get both parts
var fileNameExtension = "." + fileName.split(".").pop();
var fileNameBase = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length()-fileNameExtension.length());

if(fileNameBase.length()>limit){
    // now limit it and set it as fileName
    fileName = fileNameBase.substring(0, limit) + fileNameExtension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers don't allow modification of the value attribute of file fields. It's a security hole, because it would allow a malicious page to retrieve an arbitrary file using a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following JavaScript to check length of the file name.

```
function valueCheck()
{
 var filePath = document.getElementById("file").value;
 var fileName = filePath.replace(/[^\\\/]+$/, "");
    if(fileName !=null && fileName.length >10)
    {
        alert('Filename if bigger');
    }
}
```

Demo URL : http://jsfiddle.net/BhaveshKachhadiya/6EPvg/6/